# Confusing behaviour in Dojo nodelist traversal

Tags: dojo

Hi I am just starting out with Dojo. I was playing with nodelist traversal and found the following behaviour.

```
dojo.query("form.searchform").forEach(function(node, index, arr){       
     var f = dojo.query("form.searchform");     
     alert(f[0]); //[object HTMLFormElement]
     alert(node); //[object HTMLFormElement]
     alert(f.children()); //[object HTMLInputElement] as expected
     alert(node.children()); //undefined. why??
});
```

Searchform is as follows:

```
<form class="searchform" name="docsearch" method="post"
action="somelink.php"><input class="searchbox" name="search"
type="text" value="" id="search" name="search" size="30"/>
</form>
```

What is happening here? I want to use node inside the foreach loop to access its children. How do I do that?

EDIT:
It is not fully clear why children() did not work, but the following code solved the problem.

```
      var f = dojo.query("form.searchform");     
      alert(f[0]); //[object HTMLFormElement]
      alert(node); //[object HTMLFormElement]
      alert(f.children()); //[object HTMLInputElement] as expected
      for(i=0;node.childNodes[i] != undefined; i++){                  
        if (node.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
            alert(node.childNodes[i].value); // gives value of searchbox.
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nodes maybe any type of nodes including text nodes, etc.  You need to check the node type to make sure its an element node. If the node you are inspecting is a text node it will not have children. Nor will it have children if the node does not actually contain children, such as a < br /> or an empty div such as < div >< /div >. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType for more details on nodes, but basically you want to change your code to:

```
dojo.query("form.searchform").forEach(function(node, index, arr){       
  var f = dojo.query("form.searchform");     
  alert(f[0]); //[object HTMLFormElement]
  alert(node); //[object HTMLFormElement]
  alert(f.children()); //[object HTMLInputElement] as expected
  if (node.nodeType == 1) {
    alert(node.children());
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope, that doesnt help.
nodeType is 1 though, the if condition is met. 
I am guessing this means node does not have children. 
It might help to note that f[0].children is also undefined. 

So, what HTMLFormElement is node referring to? searchform is the only form in the html page.

Comment: NodeType doesn't guarantee it has children. It just says its an element node. And I didn't notice this before but isnt it node.childNodes not node.children ?

Comment: yes, I am wondering what that node is.
If I do alert(node.innerHTML) inside the if block, I get:
<input class="searchbox" name="search" type="text" value="search for doctors" id="search" size="30">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
why is this not a child?
and children is a dojo function http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.5/dojo/NodeList/children

Comment: alert(node.childNodes[0]) gives me [object Text]. node.childNodes[0].nodeValue is empty. where did the text box disappear?

Comment: Looks like a text node. Is there a space or new line between the form tag and the input tag. If that's the case that's the node you are seeing and the input is the next node in the list.

Comment: yup correct..  A for loop to find the right element worked fine! Still not clear why children didnt work, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: Children wont work because the node is a text node and children are nodes that are within another node - the node you had is a text node and it can not have any children.